# RemotePlaybackClient, stop() not getting callback

Tags: android, google-cast, chromecast

I am attempting to write a `RemotePlaybackClient` sample app, in part because [the one published by Google crashes **`aapt`**](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66989).

I can get `RemotePlaybackClient` to support `play()`, and it plays back a video on a Chromecast.

However, when I call `stop()`, to stop playback of the video, while the Chromecast does stop playback (showing a black screen with a cast icon centered), the `SessionActionCallback` that I pass into the `stop()` call does not get called with `onResult()`:

```
  private void stop() {
    logToTranscript(getActivity().getString(R.string.stop_requested));

    SessionActionCallback stopCB=new SessionActionCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onResult(Bundle data, String sessionId,
                           MediaSessionStatus sessionStatus) {
        logToTranscript(getActivity().getString(R.string.stopped));
        isPlaying=false;
        isPaused=false;
        getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        endSession();
      }
    };

    client.stop(null, stopCB);
  }
```

The same thing happens if I try `pause()` -- the `SessionActionCallback` passed to `pause()` is not invoked.

[The sample code published by Google](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/kitkat-mr1.1-release/samples/Support7Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv7/media/RemotePlayer.java) shows that these callbacks should be invoked, but, again, I can't get that to compile successfully.

Does anyone know under what circumstances the `SessionActionCallback` would not work, while the `ItemActionCallback` used with `play()` *would* work?

**UPDATE**

I have filed [issue 66996](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66996) and [issue 67032](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67032), the latter of which is specifically the problem I am seeing here, as I run into this same problem with the official sample app.

Comment: I did get the sample to compile in Eclipse, and it too is not receiving anything on its `SessionActionCallback` when `stop()` or `pause()` is called.

Comment: What receiver are you using?

Comment: @AliNaddaf: I am using a Chromecast from a hardware standpoint. `RemotePlaybackClient` does not specify a receiver, near as I can tell, so presumably under the covers Chromecast is using the default receiver.

Comment: The first time I call `stop`, from the sample app, a `MediaRouteProviderProtocol.SERVICE_MSG_GENERIC_FAILURE` occurs, but pressing it once more will call `SessionActionCallback.onResult` twice. So, it seems like `RegisteredMediaRouteProvider.sendControlRequest` isn't being called the first time around, for some reason.

Comment: @adneal: Where you are seeing `SERVICE_MSG_GENERIC_FAILURE`, since `stop()` is `void`?

Comment: @CommonsWare I compiled the `MediaRouter` lib in Eclipse then logged the `Handler` that receives each `Message` in `RegisteredMediaRouteProvider`.

Comment: @adneal: Ah! OK, I'll do some more poking around on this, though probably not until April. Thanks!

Comment: hopefully this may at the least indicate for you a work-around https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/android-4.4_r1.1%5E2%5E2..android-4.4_r1.1%5E2/

Answer (score 1):

I beleive all Answer reside on how you make connection.
Because in google code ,code says that client which you had made shold not leave session and should not be null.

```
if (!mClient.hasSession()) {
   // ignore if no session
   return;
}
```

/*********Rest of the code would be unreachable***********/

```
@Override
public void pause() {
    if (!mClient.hasSession()) {
        // ignore if no session
        return;
    }
    if (DEBUG) {
        Log.d(TAG, "pause");
    }
    mClient.pause(null, new SessionActionCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Bundle data, String sessionId, MediaSessionStatus sessionStatus) {
            logStatus("pause: succeeded", sessionId, sessionStatus, null, null);
            if (mCallback != null) {
                mCallback.onPlaylistChanged();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(String error, int code, Bundle data) {
            logError("pause: failed", error, code);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand your answer.

Comment: I think he's saying that he thinks you don't have a session, so it's hitting that return statement.